# You can `memset()` over a string in windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, undefined-behavior

I'm working on porting some to linux, and I discovered a rather interesting bug in the code that apparently works on windows, but not linux. A class with some string members was being initialized via `memset(this)`, which apparently works on windows, but throws a segmentation fault on linux in the string destructor.

<sub><sup>Yes, I know using `memset()` for this is horrible practice, and I'm fixing it.</sup></sub>

SSCCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::string tmp;
    std::cout << "String instantiated" << std::endl;
    memset(&tmp, 0, sizeof(tmp));
    std::cout << "String memset" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This runs fine on windows, but the string destructor segfaults on linux.

Compilers:

- MSVC++ 2013 (Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x64)
- g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

I understand that this was (and is) horrible practice either way, but how did it ever work in the first place?

Comment: What on earth was the intention here? Maybe leftover from when `tmp` was a `char` array?

Comment: A bug, an implementation detail and horrible - why do you ask (leave it alone) ?

Comment: @JosephMansfield - No **FREAKING** idea. The codebase is ~50KLOC of uncommented C++. My best guess is that the class originally had only C type members (where this use of memset is functional, if horrible), and the string member was added later without looking at the constructor, and it just somehow works anyways.

Comment: Undefined behaviour includes the possibility of fooling you into thinking that everything went ok. One possibility would be a variant of the "short string" optimization, in which a std::string with all bytes set to 0 is interpreted as an empty string.

Comment: @DieterLücking - Is curiosity dead?

Comment: @FakeName Yes, if any windows API/implementation is involved (In other words curiosity up to the point it 'works')

Comment: @DieterLücking - Point taken, also hahahahahahahah.

Comment: Here's a guess - MSVC uses short string optimization, so `memset`ting a default constructed `string` to `0` probably doesn't cause the implementation to do anything segfault worthy in that case. libstdc++ uses a (now non-standard) reference counted implementation. So it probably dynamically allocates a reference count object upon default construction. Your `memset` then gets in the way of managing this object upon destruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to dig into implementation details, MSVC and Clang (with libc++) use `string` with short-string optimization, which looks roughly like this:

```
class string {
    size_t length;
    char* ptr;
    char short_buf[N];
};
```

So if it's `memset` to `0`, its destructor will think that its length is zero and probably will do nothing, and also even if it attempts to `delete[] ptr`, it won't crash because `delete` works fine with null pointers.

GCC, on the opposite, until very recent time used quite different `string` impementation which involved copy on write and reference-counting. So its internal structure is much more complicated and it's no surprise it crashes after `memset`.

Comment: This is actually the point I was asking about. Basically, undefined behaviour like this is a interesting window into the compiler/stdlib internals.

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> how did it ever work in the first place?

Consider an implementation like below:

```
class string
{
   public:

      string() : size_(0), data_(nullptr) {}

      string(char const* s) : size_(strlen(s)), data_(new char(size_+1))
      {
         strcpy(data_, s);
      }

      ~string()
      {
         if ( data_ )
         {
            delete [] data_;
         }
      }

   private:
      size_t size_;
      char* data_;
};
```

Given such an implementation and if `nullptr` is represented by `0` (which is the most common representation),

```
string s1;
memset(&s1, 0, sizeof(s1));  // Has no impact on s1

string s2("This is a test");
memset(&s2, 0, sizeof(s2));  // Makes s2 the same as a default
                             // constructed string with memory leak
                             // as a side effect. Still, it is
                             // not going to cause segementation
                             // fault.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually getting a segfault when the program is exiting (at return 0) if you check with a debugger because the program is trying to deallocate the std::string tmp which it thinks is on the stack and then fails because it doesn't find a valid std::string at the location.

**Edit:**

It might work on one OS and not another because it's not specified by the C++ standard, and any specific implementation of deallocating std::string may be different as long as they conform to the standard. It just so happens that the implementation your using on Linux does not handle this well, but it doesn't need to because it's not a situation memset should be used for. If you want to use memset on a string, use a C style string.

Comment: I know why I'm getting a sefgault on linux, why does it *not* segfault on windows.

Comment: @FakeName To repeat another commenter: It´s undefined behaviour, anything can happen. What part do you not understand?

Comment: @deviantfan - So, what is the compiler *actually* doing in the "undefined" portion? I know you shouldn't (and can't) *depend* on undefined behaviour, but it's doing *something*, What is the something?

Comment: It's happening, *by coincidence* to do exactly what the original programmer intended.  You cannot rely on this.

Comment: re - "what is the compiler actually doing in the "undefined" portion": it's not the compiler that's doing anything. it's the implementation of the std::string class provided by the library.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor, I clarified my response.